# Convert from Windows-1252 to utf-8 in java

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, windows-1252

When I use this http://string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx and I set `encode` with : `Windows-1252` and `decode` with: `utf-8`.

And **I put this string**:

`ÐšÑšÐ¸Ð¶ÐµÐ²Ð½Ð° Ð·Ð°Ñ˜ÐµÐ´Ð½Ð¸Ñ†Ð° ÐÐ¾Ð²Ð¾Ð³ Ð¡Ð°Ð´Ð°`

**I get normal result :** `Књижевна заједница Новог Сада`.

But when i try that in java with **this method** :

```
public static String convertString(String s) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String t = new String (s.getBytes("Windows-1252"), "UTF-8");
}
```

**I get this as result :** `Књижевна заједница �?овог Сада`.

Any idea ?

Comment: have you tried s.getBytes("UTF-8")? (Maybe your input string is already correctly encoded)

Comment: can you by chance post the bytes here?

Comment: Bytes are :[B@320de756
Bytes are :[B@2eced8c6
first one is if i use getBytes("UTF-8"), second one is getBytes("Windows-1252")

Comment: we need the bytes as hex, not the object respresentation that java prints. Use: String.format("%02X ", b)

Comment: i cant convert like that, there is an error : java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: x != [B

Comment: here is hex presentation of bytes from base : C390C5A1C391C5A1C390C2B8C390C2B6C390C2B5C390C2B2C390C2BDC390C2B020C390C2B7C390C2B0C391CB9CC390C2B5C390C2B4C390C2BDC390C2B8C391E280A0C390C2B020C390C29DC390C2BEC390C2B2C390C2BEC390C2B320C390C2A1C390C2B0C390C2B4C390C2B0

Comment: That's the UTF-8 encoding. How did you define the String passed to `convertString()`?

Comment: i just get it from database, this java method s.getBytes("Windows-1252") is not working correct, so i have to find some other way to convert this

Comment: Can you get value from database directly? (the SQL may be `select rawtohex(columnName) from tableName...`)
The result of `new java.lang.String("Књижевна заједница Новог Сада".getBytes("UTF-8"), "Windows-1252").getBytes("UTF-8")` is 
C390C5A1C391C5A1 C390C2B8C390C2B6 
C390C2B5C390C2B2 C390C2BDC390C2B0
20C390C2B7C390C2‌​ B0C391CB9CC390C2 
B5C390C2B4C390C2 BDC390C2B8C391E2
80A0C390C2B020C3 90**EFBFBD**C390C2BE 
C39‌​0C2B2C390C2BE C390C2B320C390C2
A1C390C2B0C390C2 B4C390C2B0

But **EFBDBD** is different to **C29D**, the better way to identify issue is get value from database.

Comment: If you've already got the value as a string, you're too late to fix any encoding problems. You should be showing us how you get the value from the database, and any relevant database settings.